# After the click does not appear in bold

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created an internal email system within the project. When I receive a new message the column with the subject name in my table is bolded to inform that the message has not yet been read.

code:

```
<?php  
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
        {  
        ?> 
<section id="s1">
<div class="div1" id="minhaDiv" style="float: left;">  
    <table class="table table-bordered">  
        <tr> 
            <th width="20%">De</th>
            <th width="60%">Assunto</th>
            <th width="10%">Prioridade</th>
            <th width="10%">Recebido</th>               
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <th width="10%" colspan=4>Recebido: <?php echo $row["Data"]; ?></th>

        </tr>       

        <tr>  
        <td><?php echo $row["De"]; ?></td> 
            <td class="td-info view_data" id="<?php echo $row["Id"]; ?>" data-toggle="modal" href="#dataModal" width="20%" style="font-weight:bold" onclick="this.style['font-weight'] ='normal'"><?php echo $row["Assunto"]; ?></td>  
        <td><?php echo $row["Prioridade"]; ?></td> 
            <td><?php echo $row["Hora"]; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <?php  
        }  
        ?> 
    </table>  
</div>
</section>
```

In the image, which is surrounded by green already clicked to read, the red has not yet vliquei to read, so it is bold:

[image]

I use this code to put bold inside the `td`:

```
width="20%" style="font-weight:bold" onclick="this.style['font-weight'] ='normal'"
```

The problem is that if you refresh the page, even after reading the messages, they come back in bold and should not. After clicking once, they can not be left in bold

Comment: Where specifically in your code do you make the text bold?  On what condition do you perform that operation?  Why specifically do you expect that condition to change after a message has been read?

Comment: @David I do not understand, I put the td "Subject" in bold, inside the td, then when I click it is no longer in bold, but I have no condition. I want to make only the new messages in bold, to know the ones I have not read yet

Comment: *"but I have no condition"* - Sounds like you need one.  *"I want to make only the new messages in bold"* - And it sounds like you already know what that condition is.  When you're rendering this data, *conditionally* make the text bold based on whether or not the message has been read.  How do you track that information?  Once you have that information, it sounds like what you're looking for is called an `if` statement in PHP.

Comment: @BrunoPinto you will have to setup your messages table in database for read/unread messages, i.e. make a column read, if receiver read the message put 1 else zero, this is how you will get a read value while looping.

Comment: @Shoyeb Sheikh I added an answer with the creation of a field in the table where I will be able to create the condition. Now how do I create the condition inside the `TD`. I'm trying like this: `width="20%" style="font-weight:bold" onclick="if(<?php echo $row["Status"] == '1'; ?> ){this.style['font-weight'] ='normal'}"`, but it does not

Comment: @BrunoPinto, try this =>    width="20%" style="font-weight:<?php echo $row["Status"] == '1' ? 'normal' : 'bold' ?>"

Comment: @Shoyeb Sheikh You're saying onclick, like this: `onclick =this => width="20%" style="font-weight:<?php echo $row["Status"] == '1' ? 'normal' : 'bold' ?>"`, returns syntax error

Comment: @BrunoPinto you dont have to use onclick event or any javascript just try this code instead of what you were trying:  `width="20%" style="font-weight:<?php echo $row["Status"] == '1' ? 'normal' : 'bold' ?>"`

Comment: @Shoyeb Sheikh Thus, both the status column and the status column are always bold

Comment: @BrunoPinto thats because $row["Status"] is not 1

Comment: @Shoyeb Sheikh  No, what I meant was, the Status column if it has a value of 1 or 0 is always in bold. Does not change color depending on the value of the Status column

Comment: @BrunoPinto you also need an ajax request to change the status when you click that td, please refer to the answer for ajax.

Comment: @Shoyeb Sheikh Solved the problem `width="20%" <?php echo $row["Status"] == '1'?' style="font-weight:bold" ':' style="font-weight:normal" '?>`

Comment: Glad you got it right in the end :)

Answer (score 0):

Solution to achieve the condition.
I created a `Status` field in the database table, where 1 is unread message and 0 message is read, now is to create the condition in td with `if`. In the javascript with which I open the modal I made the following change:

```
$('.td-info').click(function(){
    var item_id = $(this).attr("id");
    var status = $(this).attr("Status");

      $.ajax({ 
        url:"./fetchRAD",  
        method: "POST",  
        data:{item_id:item_id, status:status},   
        success:function(data){ 
                }
      });               
    });
```

In `td` I indicated the `id` of the record in the `id` of `td`:

```
id="<?php echo $row["Id"]; ?>"
```

file with `php`:

```
if(isset($_POST["item_id"]))  
 {      
      $query = "Update centrodb.Alertas SET Status = '0' WHERE Id = '".$_POST["item_id"]."'";  
      $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

 }
```

Pata check in the `td` we put like this:

```
width="20%" <?php echo $row["Status"] == '1'?' style="font-weight:bold" ':' style="font-weight:normal" '?>
```

`td` complete:

```
<td class="td-info view_data" id="<?php echo $row["Id"]; ?>" data-toggle="modal" href="#dataModal" width="20%" <?php echo $row["Status"] == '1'?' style="font-weight:bold" ':' style="font-weight:normal" '?>><?php echo $row["Assunto"]; ?></td>
```